# Веб приложение на сокетах

Tags: python, веб-программирование, php, websocket, сокет

Доброго времени суток, мне необходимо реализовать следующее, буду благодарен если кто-нибудь пнет в нужную сторону.

Есть сервер A, который по обычному TCP сокету ежесекундно раздает всем клиентам информацию.

Есть хост с PHP и Python, который рендерит страницу и она должна ежесекундно получать эту информацию в код JS.

К тому же после получения N сообщений необходимо провести операцию с БД, поэтому в любом случае в промежутке стоит скрипт на хосте.

Вопрос:

1) Возможно ли что-то подобное на PHP? В качестве обмена с веб-страницей ничего лучше вебсокетов с фоллбеком на флэш в голову не пришло, но не нашел ни одной нормальной реализации на PHP.

2) Пишу я это на Python с Tornado, каким образом мне в одном скрипте получать данные по одному сокету и передавать по другому? Распараллелить средствами Python?

Comment: На PHP есть веб-сервер - WaterSpout вроде - у нас по longpoling с клиентами общается.

Там правда косячки иногда бывают - иногда, когда сервер закрывает соединение, ответ клиенту не всегда послан. Т.е. браузер считает что запрос не обработан и посылает второй запрос. При этом в браузере отображается только одна посылка. В итоге запрос обрабатывается два раза. Бывает такое редко и при большой нагрузке. Возможно где-то у нас косяк - пока не смотрели.

Работает с jsonp - на html-клиентах его как прокси используем

Answer (score 0, accepted):

я думаю Вам больше подойдет node.js + socket.io

Можно использовать node.js в качестве передатчика между клиентом и сервером.

Comment: Несомненно отличная идея, но там shared с PHP, Python и Perl.

Comment: я имею ввиду сервер node.js использовать в качестве маршрута. Тоесть пользователь с клиента отдает данные на node.js, а node.js отдает к вам на связку "PHP, Python и Perl", далее они отвечают и node.js снова передает клиенту. 

Вот такое вот взаимодействие. Честно говоря не знаю, как будет по нагрузке и скорости выполнения, но думаю в любом случае лучше чем дергать каждую секунду сетинтервалом в js. 

В любом случае вся работа в на сокетах держится. В node.js буквально пару функций для передачи данных туда обратно.

Comment: Если у вас shared хостинг то наверное лучше воспользоватся комет сервером предоставляемым по модели SAAS или арендовать vps и поставить туда какойнибудь готовый комет сервер с php api